# Linear independence of a set of 'simple' functions

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, polynomials

I have some $\alpha = \{f_0(x),f_1(x),\dots,f_n(x)\}$

Where having the $k$ in $f_k(x)$ equal $x$, meaning $k=x$ makes $f_k(x)=1$ or zero if $k \ne x$.

Now I want to show $\alpha$ is linearly independent, which it is if you sub in each $x=k$. But doesn't that require that I have $n+1$ different $\alpha_n$ which are all linearly independent(each with $x=\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n\}$)?

Comment: I can't make sense of showing $\alpha$ is linearly independent, when normally I check that multiple vectors are linearly independent...?

Comment: You need to start looking at the set of functions as a vector space, @Diplay Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for some choice of real numbers $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^n$ you have $f(x):=\sum_0^n a_if_i(x)=0$ for all $x$. Then

$f(0)=a_0f_0(0)=0$

$f(1)=a_1f_1(1)=0$

$\dots$

$f(n)=a_nf_n(n)=0$.

Do you see that all the coefficients $\{a_i\}_{i=0}^n$ have to be zero? By the definition of linear independence, $\alpha$ is a linearly independent set.

Comment: Very good call, thank you!

Comment: For this linear independence, how can I test it for all $x$? I can see when I have a specific $x$ that they have to be all $a_i = 0$, but I am not sure how to generalize.

Comment: To establish linear independence of the functions $f_i$, in the vector space of functions, I proved that any linear combination of $f_i$ that yields the zero function has zero coefficients. (This is the definition of linear independence.) To this end I calculated $f(i)=a_if_i(i)=0$ which gives $a_i=0$. That is all that needed to be done.

Comment: Do you understand that for any value of $x$ the values $f_i(x)$ are real numbers and not functions?

Comment: Yep to the second comment, and I get it now with the first one. Thank you again!